# Best Practice - Allow offline use of android app?

Tags: android

currently I'am developing an Android native app which have to communicate with a server (for ex. via REST) to load, save data etc.

Now I'm considering the offline scenario. I also want the user to save data if the mobile phone has currently not network connection. If the network connection is up again I want to sync the user data with my server.

Do anyone know some best practice to achieve this. I'm considering using a couchdb for replication, but I'm wondering if there are other nice ways to support offline use of my app.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use broad cast receiver for this purpose

```
 <receiver android:name=".ConnectionReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

if connectivity is changed(on or off) we can know that using this broadcast receiver...and start a assynctask for u r refresh and load the new data from server